# Бесплатна ли Oracle JDK для коммерческих целей c 18 версии

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdk11, openjdk

Вроде как начиная с 18 версии jdk от oracle теперь бесплатна. Но как я понял в некоторых случаях она все-равно платная. Не являюсь юристом, чтобы точно понимать новую лицензию. Хотел бы спросить тех, кто использует в проде Oracle JDK как сейчас обстоят дела?

Comment: Илья Кузьмич, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Answer (score 0):

Не использую её в проде, но https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/ совершенно ясно говорит, что лицензия бесплатна для прода - "JDK 18 and JDK 17 binaries are free to use in production and free to redistribute". Фишка может быть в том, что с сентября её заменят на JDK 19, а вот будет ли она бесплатной - вопрос.
Вы бы лучше описали источники информации, что она платная, тогда можно более предметно отвечать.

Comment: А что вы думаете об [этом](https://java.com/ru/download/help/error_embargoed_ru.html)? Новые реальности нашей жизни